# Are there languages which don't use "=" to mean set this to that value?

Tags: syntax

Today I was thinking about programming style and equals signs and how awful it looks when people don't put spaces around them and it got me thinking:

**Are there languages where setting the value of something is not (primarily) expressed via an "=" sign?**

And not to shoehorn this in, but are there languages that use "=" for comparison operations (as opposed to "==")?

Comment: I believe Pascal uses := instead of =

Comment: (And there are even some languages that would treat `x= y` and `x = y` differently; in any case, I gave a -1 because "Are there ..?" is a question that is clearly "yes". Also, see the FAQ.)

Comment: Haskell only uses `=` for definition, never for setting values.

Comment: @casperOne this is ridiculous. This question might be genral but it is ENTIRELY constructive, by definition of constructive in the FAQ this question CAN be supported by: "facts, references, or specific expertise" in fact specific expertise especially because there are TONS of languages and I figured that the broad expertise on SO would yield useful fringe cases.

Comment: @pst you are misinterpreting my permeable for my question, I am not curious about spaces per se, just what the equals sign means in different languages.

Comment: @MarkFox I was not misinterpreting the "question". My comment was not about spaces per se, but rather an example that syntax grammar is not universal. (Once realizing this, the "question" starts to look very Not Constructive.)

Comment: @pst of course grammar it's not universal, the nature of my question is curious about these outliers specifically.

Comment: @MarkFox Then search for it; that is why I gave the -1. There are too many different syntaxes over too many different paradigms (some of which don't even have assignment) for this to represent any form of "practical, answerable problem". See [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code) (or Wikipedia/c2wiki as shown) for such cursory syntax overviews.

Comment: @MarkFox It's a list question, which we close as not constructive.  You're asking to maintain a list of languages which assignment is not represented through the "=" operator.  The problem with list questions is that every answer is equally valid.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139618/140951 for more details.

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia has a great table showing various operators in languages: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)#Notation.

Tables reproduced below (screenshoted):

[image]

[image]

[image]

All tables from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_%28computer_science%29#Notation).

Comment: I thought I could reproduce these tables in Markdown but SO doesn't support it :\. That's why I resorted to screenshots

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Pascal uses `:=` for assignment.

Visual Basic uses `=` for comparison and for assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Sure! For example, many LISP family languages express assignments (and other operations) in a left-to-right pattern

```
(set! x (+ 1 2 3))
```

This is called *prefix* notation, whereas `x = 1 + 2 + 3` as another language might do would be *infix* notation. The fact that the symbol `=` is not used is secondary, and probably due more to it looking odd in prefix notation than anything else.

POSIX Shell and its variants use `=` for assignment in one context, but in another for comparison, as in after the `[` command:

```
[ "$x" = "abc" ]
```

As an aside, `sh` doesn't care about your aesthetic: If you use `=` for assignment you'd better not include whitespace!

```
$ z = 1
-bash: z: command not found
```